# Large differences in mex function execution time depending on place of memory allocation

Tags: c, memory, time, mex

I have a Matlab mex function which makes repeated calls to a C function called `calculate().` I made two versions of the functions:

Version A: Each time `mex()` calls `calculate()`, it passes only the input parameters, and all memory needed by `calculate()` is allocated and freed inside `calculate()` -- each time!

Version B: The memory needed by `calculate()` is allocated at the beginning of `mex()`, and pointers are passed to `calculate()`. Memory is freed only at the end of `mex()`. In other words, the allocating/freeing is only done once for the whole business.

I created version B under the naïve assumption that this should improve speed, according to the notion that memory allocation takes time. But it actually increased execution time by about 5x! What is going on there?

Here's the actual code for Version B-- you can see from the comments where I originally had the memory allocation for Version A.

```
/* MEX business*/
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]){
   /* mexPrintf("Inside the mex function of CalcMz2.\n");
mexEvalString("drawnow;");*/

/*declare local variables*/
struct InputParameters voxelPars;
InputParameters *point2pars;
struct Zcontrast contrast;
struct Zcontrast* ptr2contrast;
ptr2contrast = &contrast;
mxArray *in, *out;
mxArray *temp; 
double *output;
int nFields;
int i,j,k;

in = mxDuplicateArray(prhs[0]); /*'in' now is a copy of the input struct*/
nFields = mxGetNumberOfFields(prhs[0]); 
if (nFields != 39) mexPrintf("Error: the number of fields in the input struct is incorrect.\n");

 //associate outputs
    out = plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleScalar(0.0);
    output = mxGetPr(out);

    /*Passed variables memory allocation*/
double **pntrA; 
pntrA = (double **)mxCalloc(18, sizeof(double*));
for (i=0; i <18; i++){
    pntrA[i] = (double *) mxCalloc(18, sizeof(double));
}
double *pntrAinvB;
pntrAinvB = (double *) mxCalloc(18, sizeof(double));


/*used by MatrInv()*/
double **CopyOfMatrix; 
CopyOfMatrix = (double**)mxCalloc(18, sizeof(double*));
for (i=0; i<18; i++){
    CopyOfMatrix[i] = (double*)mxCalloc(18, sizeof(double));
  }

double *vector;
double *col;
int *indx;
vector = (double *)mxCalloc(18, sizeof(double));
indx = (int *)mxCalloc(18, sizeof(int));
col = (double *)mxCalloc(18, sizeof(double));

/*used by CalculateY()*/
double *Aat; 
Aat = (double*)mxCalloc(18*18, sizeof(double));

double *Aate; 
Aate = (double*)mxCalloc(18*18, sizeof(double));

double *sum;
sum = (double*)mxCalloc(18, sizeof(double));
double *product;
product = (double*)mxCalloc(18, sizeof(double));

/*Reassign values passed from input struct*/ 
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,0);
voxelPars.ampl = mxGetPr(temp);
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,1);
voxelPars.phi = mxGetPr(temp);
temp  =  mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,2);
voxelPars.count1 = mxGetScalar(temp);
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,3);
voxelPars.pw1 = mxGetScalar(temp);
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,4);
voxelPars.b1 = mxGetScalar(temp);
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,5);
voxelPars.puloffsetppm = mxGetScalar(temp);
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,6);
voxelPars.pw1dc = mxGetScalar(temp);
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,7);
voxelPars.cf = mxGetScalar(temp); 
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,8);
voxelPars.M0w = mxGetScalar(temp); 
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,9);
voxelPars.T1a = mxGetScalar(temp); 
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,10);
voxelPars.T2a = mxGetScalar(temp); 
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,11);
voxelPars.offsetappm = mxGetScalar(temp); 
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,12);
voxelPars.bwfraction = mxGetScalar(temp); 
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,13);
voxelPars.M0a = mxGetScalar(temp); 
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,14);
voxelPars.M0bw = mxGetScalar(temp); 
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,15);
voxelPars.T1bw = mxGetScalar(temp); 
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,16);
voxelPars.T2bw = mxGetScalar(temp); 
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,17);
voxelPars.offsetbwppm = mxGetScalar(temp); 
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,18);
voxelPars.exratebw = mxGetScalar(temp); 
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,19);
voxelPars.M0b = mxGetScalar(temp); 
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,20);
voxelPars.T1b = mxGetScalar(temp); 
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,21);
voxelPars.T2b = mxGetScalar(temp); 
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,22);
voxelPars.offsetbppm = mxGetScalar(temp); 
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,23);
voxelPars.exrateb = mxGetScalar(temp); 
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,24);
voxelPars.M0c = mxGetScalar(temp); 
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,25);
voxelPars.T1c = mxGetScalar(temp); 
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,26);
voxelPars.T2c = mxGetScalar(temp); 
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,27);
voxelPars.offsetcppm = mxGetScalar(temp); 
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,28);
voxelPars.exratec = mxGetScalar(temp);
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,29);
voxelPars.M0d = mxGetScalar(temp); 
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,30);
voxelPars.T1d = mxGetScalar(temp); 
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,31);
voxelPars.T2d = mxGetScalar(temp); 
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,32);
voxelPars.offsetdppm = mxGetScalar(temp); 
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,33);
voxelPars.exrated = mxGetScalar(temp); 
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,34);
voxelPars.M0e = mxGetScalar(temp); 
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,35);
voxelPars.T1e = mxGetScalar(temp); 
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,36);
voxelPars.T2e = mxGetScalar(temp); 
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,37);
voxelPars.offseteppm = mxGetScalar(temp); 
temp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],0,38);
voxelPars.exratee = mxGetScalar(temp); 

point2pars = &voxelPars;


/*Initialize contrast's values to zero*/
ptr2contrast->SimMza = ptr2contrast->SimMzb = ptr2contrast->contrastz = 1.0;

/* call calculate()*/
calculate(point2pars, ptr2contrast, pntrA, pntrAinvB, CopyOfMatrix,vector,  col, indx, Aat, Aate, sum, product);
*output = ptr2contrast->contrastz; 
//mexPrintf("The contrast has been calculated as :%f.\n",     ptr2contrast->contrastz);


/*Free memory
 mxFree(pntrA); mxFree(pntrAinvB);*/
 mxFree(CopyOfMatrix); mxFree(Aat); mxFree(Aate);
 mxFree(vector);mxFree(indx);mxFree(col);
 mxFree(sum); mxFree(product);
}//end mex function   



void calculate (struct InputParameters *voxelPars1, struct Zcontrast       *contrast,  double **pntrA,double *pntrAinvB, double **CopyOfMatrix, double *vector, double *col,int *indx, double *Aat, double *Aate, double *sum, double *product){  

/*Local variables*/
int i, j, k, n1, m; 
double pwms, pw1delay;
int npul; 
double timeStepSize; 
double W;
double Wa, Wbw, Wb, Wc, Wd, We;
double Cbw, Cb, Cc, Cd, Ce;
double M0a, M0bw, M0b, M0c, M0d, M0e; //declaring these as locals just to make life easier
double pa, pbw, pb, pc, pd, pe;
double Cabw, Cab, Cac, Cad, Cae;
double k1a, k1bw, k1b, k1c, k1d, k1e;
double k2a, k2bw, k2b, k2c, k2d, k2e;

//     double **pntrA; 
//     pntrA = (double **)mxCalloc(18, sizeof(double*));
//     for (i=0; i <18; i++){
//         pntrA[i] = (double *) mxCalloc(18, sizeof(double));


  //     }
   //           
    double AdinvB[18];
    double AinvB[18];
    for(i=0; i<18; i++){
          AdinvB[i] = 0.0;
         AinvB[i] = 0.0;
     }
//    
// /*Passed variables memory allocation*/
//     double **CopyOfMatrix; /*used by MatriInv()*/
//     CopyOfMatrix = (double**)mxCalloc(18, sizeof(double*));
//     for (i=0; i<18; i++){
//         CopyOfMatrix[i] = (double*)mxCalloc(18, sizeof(double));
//       }
//     
//     double *vector;
//     double *col;
//     int *indx;
//     vector = (double *)mxCalloc(18, sizeof(double));
//     indx = (int *)mxCalloc(18, sizeof(int));
//     col = (double *)mxCalloc(18, sizeof(double));
//     
//     /*used by CalculateY()*/
//     double *Aat; 
//     Aat = (double*)mxCalloc(18*18, sizeof(double));
//    /* for (i=0; i<18; i++){
//         Aat[i] = (double*)mxCalloc(18, sizeof(double));
//     }*/
//     
//     double *Aate; 
//     Aate = (double*)mxCalloc(18*18, sizeof(double));
//    /* for (i=0; i<18; i++){
//         Aate[i] = (double*)mxCalloc(18, sizeof(double));
//     }   */
//      
//     double *sum;
//     sum = (double*)mxCalloc(18, sizeof(double));
//     double *product;
//     product = (double*)mxCalloc(18, sizeof(double));

    double W1[voxelPars1->count1]; //Now THIS might require a pointer, since count1 is only passed in the argument struct. We'll see.
    double W1x[voxelPars1->count1];
    double W1y[voxelPars1->count1];
   /* mexPrintf("Declared all local variables in calculate().\n");
    mexEvalString("drawnow;");*/

    /*Fill local variables with values from input struct voxelPars*/
```

....calculate keeps going after that

Comment: And you thought the code wouldn't be relevant here?

Comment: show your work here,your code may have some problem.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problems recently. While I don't have any insight into matlab memory management facilities, I can say that for me switching to C-native malloc/free  gave a roughly x5 speedup.

It seems that in your case too, there is no need to manage memory on the Matlab heap (using mxCalloc and similar) - since the memory allocation is for mex-function internal use only. Suggest you try it: just replace mxCalloc with malloc, mxFree with free.